# Aptana3 Code Assist with the Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, aptana, aptana3

I'm trying to enable Code Assist for Google Maps API v3 in Aptana3.
It does not seem to work.

I followed the instructions from [this page](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/JavaScript+Library+Support):

> Drop the VSDoc files into your Web Project.
>
> V3 Maps API: gmapvsdoc.codeplex.com

As instructed, I got the zip file from [Google Maps API 3 Visual Studio Intellisense Helper](https://gmapvsdoc.codeplex.com/)

I extracted **google-maps-3-vs-1-0.js** and **google-maps-3-vs-1-0-vsdoc.js** in a **scripts** folder in my project (a PHP project).

This is how I included the API in my html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/google-maps-3-vs-1-0.js"></script>
```

The API works fine. I can access all its features.
Yet, when I type 'map.' (after initializing the variable with *var map = new google.maps.Map(...)*) Aptana has no proposals to assist me with.

Is Aptana3 not compatible with Google Maps API v3?

Have I done something wrong?

Could it be because I'm also using the JQuery Code Assist?

Comment: Does the vsdoc actually work with aptana?  I know it works with visual studio I just would be suprised if it worked with aptana.